# Android save LocalContacts into Database

Tags: android, database, android-contacts

Here is how local contacts are saved into database 1 by 1. This method lasts for about 20-30 sec. The while works really slow

```
 public StringBuilder getLocalContacts(Context context, List<Contact> contactList) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
            null);
             // this while works slow
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));


        if (Integer.valueOf(hasPhone) == 1) {
            String contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            // You know it has a number so now query it like this
            Cursor phones = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
            while (phones.moveToNext()) {

                Contact contact = new Contact();

                contact.setFullName(contactName);
                contact.setAddressBookId(contactId);
                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                contact.setPhone(phoneNumber);
                sb.append(phoneNumber).append("|");

                Cursor emails = context.getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                while (emails.moveToNext()) {
                    // This would allow you get several email addresses
                    String emailAddress = emails.getString(emails
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    contact.setEmail(emailAddress);
                    break;
                }
                emails.close();
                contactList.add(contact);
            }
            phones.close();
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    return sb;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what would make this method do the job in about 1 sec? or is there any faster method?

Comment: Move it in another thread (async task?) and use a wait message would be an idea..

Comment: this method is called from inside an async task, and after that i make requests to server in order to bind that db with local db. the strange thing is that working with server lasts like 1/2 sec (comparing and binding all the contacts) but only processing local contacts lasts like 20 sec.